# Primary is to Secondary as Principal is to...what?

Tags: single-word-requests, computing

If something is divided into *principal* divisions, what is the next level "down"?

For example, if a generic term for a US state or Canadian province is a "principal country division", what is a good name for the next level down, like a county?

Edit: I'll probably just go with Primary Division and Secondary Division, unless someone has a better idea.

Comment: subdivisions?   .

Comment: _Secondary country division_. _Primary_ means "first", _secondary_ means "1 level down", _tertiary_ means "one level below **that**". If you need more than three you should probly rethink your writing strategy.

Comment: Maybe the question is: "Secondary" is to "primary" as _what_ is to "principal"? Also, why the _computing_ tag?

Comment: @martinf changed the title, as yours is better. "Computing" because this is to name database tables.

Comment: Off topic (name the variable question). While similar questions may be on-topic here, most are unlikely to help future readers because the constraints of the particular circumstances are generally unique.

Comment: @MετάEd I disagree. Almost every database has a "state" or "state_or_province" table or column. There are literally dozens of books on data modeling and none of them can decide on a term. Unfortunately the common term appears to be Principal Division, but there's no consensus about the level beneath that, hence my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Primary is to Secondary as Principal is to subordinate/supplemental or subsidiary.
..a level down.

Primary Division and Secondary Division vs. Principal Division and supplemental Division.

It's more a matter of choice and prevalent usage.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean 'of lesser importance' I think **[Subsidiary](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/subsidiary)** works as an opposite of principal.**[Auxiliary](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/auxiliary)** is another such word. But in general these mean lower in function or importance and not lower down in a graph hierarchy or a map. In that sense principle and secondary are better as you indicated.

Answer (score 0):

Primary is to secondary as principal is to **accesory**.

*Auxiliary* and *subsidiary* have a stronger connotation of giving assistance. *Accesory* relates to principal in a more neutral way, as primary relates to secondary.